# Sanity check for Carmichael numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, carmichael-numbers

I made a simple calculation in Sagemath (see [[1]](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=syzrvy)) to check results of Table in [2](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1989-53-187/S0025-5718-1989-0969484-8/S0025-5718-1989-0969484-8.pdf), for producing a Carmichael number with three prime factors. I used the parameters of the previous table, and as far as I understood, I have to take a Carmichael number of the form $P\cdot Q\cdot R,$ and $P,Q,R,$ are prime numbers.

```
T = product(Primes()[1:15])
A,C,X = 35, 135449, 83421
#A,C,X = 41,141847,803985
def dubner_parameters(T,A,C,X):

    M = ((T*C-1)^A)/4
    P = 6*M + 1
    Q = 12*M + 1
    R = 1 + (P*Q-1)/X
    N = P*Q*R
    return N,P,Q,R,M
N,P,Q,R,M = dubner_parameters(T,A,C,X)
```

Checking `is_prime(P)`
I got false. I expected to get true. What I made wrong?

Comment: Not every product of $3$ distinct primes is a Carmichael number. All the primes must be odd and we must have $\ p-1 \mid N-1\ $ for every prime factor $\ p\ $ of $\ N\ $.

Comment: @Peter Correct. But here I just apply the parameters provided by the paper, and I assumed that will generate Carmichael numbers. See the paper.

Comment: If $p_1,...,p_n$ are n distinct odd  primes with $n\ge 3$ then their product $N$ is Carmichael iff  $lcm(p_1-1,...,p_n-1)$ divides $N-1.$ It is necessary (but not sufficient) that $p_i\not \equiv 1 \mod p_j$  whenever $ i\ne j.$